# Random walk with drift and trend

Tags: self-study, trend, random-walk

I am currently having a problem regarding the process,
so this was the equation

$$Y_t = \alpha + Y_{t-1} + \beta t + \epsilon_t$$

where, $\epsilon_t \sim WN(0, \sigma^2)$

I was calculating the $E(y)$ then the $V(y)$ however,
[image]
I cant be sure now whether I am doing it correctly or not. If the following process is right, will the $Cov (t – \tau)= \sigma^2$ ?

Comment: Hi: I gave you the way to do it earlier. did you attempt that approach ? you can use your approach but, if you're interested in time-series, then you need to understand how the lag operator works eventually, so why not learn it now ? If you don't want to, then hopefully someone will guide you through your approach. It's very messy and I don't have time to write it all out.

Comment: Hello mlofton, I have seen your reply, thank you for your interest, I am currently trying to learn L operator from online sources. 
Learning from online takes a bit more time than asking direct questions :)

Comment: Please address the issues in your previous question that was closed instead of deleting it and posting the same question again   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495457/random-walk-with-drift-and-trend

Comment: Thanks for the edits; I am rather new and don't know exactly what to do Sextus, I edited the closed question, but nothing changed. So I thought I should delete that one

Comment: No problem. I'm not sure what a good reference for the lag operator is ? Maybe Hamilton ? Putting an answer below since it might not be easy to find a good one.

Answer (score 1):

$ Y_t = \alpha + Y_{t-1} + \beta \times t + \epsilon_t $

$  Y_t (1 - L) = \alpha + \beta \times t + \epsilon_t $

$ Y_t = \frac{\alpha}{1-L}+\frac{\beta t}{1-L} + \frac{\epsilon_t}{1-L} $ (diving by $1-L$).

First term is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\alpha $ because there is no $t$.

Second term $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \beta (t-i)$

Third term is  $\sum_{i=0}^\infty \epsilon_{t-i}$

The first, second and third terms explode so there is no mean and variance. The process is explosive. But we should have known this immediately because the coefficient of $Y_{t-1} = 1 $ which is called a unit root process which is not stationary. If the coefficient of $Y_{t-1}$ had a coefficient that was less than one and there was no $\beta t$ term, then a mean and variance could be calculated using the lag operator notation. I hope this helped some.

Comment: @Stormborn Michael: I just read title and a random walk is always explosive which was another STRONG ( beyond strong actually )  hint that there was no mean and variance. My bad for not reading title carefully.